# Why Page Redirects To Login In Angular 4/2

Tags: angular, local-storage, token, angular-services

Why is it my angular program redirects to login page after i refresh my page. I already stored my token in local storage but why it redirects me to login page after refreshing it. Or when i click a menu and open it in  a new tab, it also redirects to login page?

> auth-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';

const authRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(authRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule {}
```

> app-routing.module.ts

```
import{ NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth-guard.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'users', loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: 'news', loadChildren: './news/news.module#NewsModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})
    ],

    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

> auth-guard.service.ts

```
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

  if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }
        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['signin'])
        return false;
    }

}
```

> auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private loggedIn = false;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  signinUser(email: string, password: string) {  
    const headers = new HttpHeaders() 
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.httpClient
    .post(
      'http://sample/login', 
       JSON.stringify({ email, password }), 
       { headers: headers }
    )
    .map(
        (response: any) => {
          localStorage.setItem('auth_token', response.token);
          this.loggedIn = true;
          return response;
        });
   }

   isLoggedIn() {
     return this.loggedIn;
  }

   logout() {
     localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
     this.loggedIn = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code for `auth-guard.service`

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic. Done

Comment: it seems that the problem is with `AuthService.isLoggedIn()` method. Something inside of that is failing to read the token from the `localStorage`. Let's see that service or that method (unless it depends on another part of the code that might be interesting to see)

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic. Ive added the auth.service.ts.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after refresh your variable  `private loggedIn = false;` is reset to false. You are not rechecking if `localStorage` has the key. Update `isLoggedIn()` to check if key exists in `localStorage`.

### Update

One way to resolve this issue is to update your constructor by adding the check for `auth_token` presence in localStorage.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('auth_token')) {
    this.loggedIn = true;
}
```

Comment: Got it. You have to put "return" in this.loggedIn = true

Answer (score 0):

That may be as per the routing defined. Can you share your routing code. This may be because the route you are currently on is mapped to Login component.

Is it that you only have a single route for your entire application? In that case when you refresh, the component is reset. Hence you will be getting the initial page. You got to preserve the state by reading the values from `localStorage` on lifecycle hook `ngOnInit` and set the variables appropriately so that you can get the same state you were before refresh. Not recommended though. Keep multiple nested routes for your application.

Comment: Can you check again

Comment: Can you check again. That auth-routing is a sub route. I have a main route in app-routing.module.ts